# Amazon SQS never returning messages in Python library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to set up 2 Lambda functions. One to gather some info from an incoming POST request and respond if the info is validated, and another to then process that info. I'm successfully (I think) sending the message to my SQS queue, but the code in the second Lambda function never returns an actual message, no matter how many times I have it poll.

I tried sending a message from the first Lambda function to the SQS queue, and then tried retrieving said message from the queue with the second Lambda function. All I get is "ResponseMetadata" in return.

EDIT: I've decided to go with SNS over SQS. I was using `boto3.client('sqs')` and `ReceiveMessage` instead of `boto3.resource('sqs')` and `ReceiveMessages`, but for my use case SNS will be faster for processing.

Comment: Can you add the code of second lambda function here?

Comment: How is the 2nd Lambda function being triggered? If you have setup SQS integration with Lambda then Lambda will be triggered with the message in the `event` object, and the message will not be available in the queue any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go with SNS over SQS. I was using boto3.client('sqs') and ReceiveMessage instead of boto3.resource('sqs') and ReceiveMessages, but for my use case SNS will be faster for processing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).